# webpack выдаёт ошибку

Tags: node.js, webpack

Народ помогите вот такая вот ошибка, что делать?

```
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle webpack-starter-config@4.17.2~prebuild: webpack-starter-config@4.17.2
6 verbose lifecycle webpack-starter-config@4.17.2~prebuild: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle webpack-starter-config@4.17.2~prebuild: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\vaide\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\webpack-starter-master\epack66.ru\node_modules\.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\vaide\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\vaide\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\vaide\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
8 verbose lifecycle webpack-starter-config@4.17.2~prebuild: CWD: C:\Users\vaide\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\webpack-starter-master\epack66.ru
9 silly lifecycle webpack-starter-config@4.17.2~prebuild: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'rimraf public && npm install' ]
10 silly lifecycle webpack-starter-config@4.17.2~prebuild: Returned: code: 0  signal: null
11 info lifecycle webpack-starter-config@4.17.2~build: webpack-starter-config@4.17.2
12 verbose lifecycle webpack-starter-config@4.17.2~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
13 verbose lifecycle webpack-starter-config@4.17.2~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\vaide\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\webpack-starter-master\epack66.ru\node_modules\.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\vaide\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\vaide\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\vaide\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
14 verbose lifecycle webpack-starter-config@4.17.2~build: CWD: C:\Users\vaide\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\webpack-starter-master\epack66.ru
15 silly lifecycle webpack-starter-config@4.17.2~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack --mode production --colors --progress' ]
16 silly lifecycle webpack-starter-config@4.17.2~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
17 info lifecycle webpack-starter-config@4.17.2~build: Failed to exec build script
18 verbose stack Error: webpack-starter-config@4.17.2 build: `webpack --mode production --colors --progress`
18 verbose stack Exit status 2
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
18 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
18 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
19 verbose pkgid webpack-starter-config@4.17.2
20 verbose cwd C:\Users\vaide\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\webpack-starter-master\epack66.ru
21 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
22 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
23 verbose node v10.16.0
24 verbose npm  v6.9.0
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error errno 2
27 error webpack-starter-config@4.17.2 build: `webpack --mode production --colors --progress`
27 error Exit status 2
28 error Failed at the webpack-starter-config@4.17.2 build script.
28 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
29 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

Comment: Что делать? Как минимум переформулировать вопрос, больше информации....

Comment: Ему вроде не нравиться версия `nodejs`...  Ему, это `webpack-У`....